# Angular directive change angle of img on event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to rotate an image every time an event is fired, but so far I've failed to get it working. It loads at the beginning, but doesn't on event changes. How do I tell the directive to 'reload'?

Here is my directive:

```
angular.module('cvApp')
  .directive('handdirection', function ($rootScope,getangle) {

    var current = 0;
    var angle = 0;
    $rootScope.$on('RouteChange', function(event, params) {
           current = params.pos;
           var getxelement = angular.element(document).find('#secondrowelement').width();
           var getyelement = angular.element(document).find('#secondrowelement').height();
           var dimension = getangle.getdimensions(getxelement,getyelement,current);
           angle = getangle.getangle(dimension);
    });

    return {
      template: '',
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            ////// turn image /////
            console.log(element);
            element.css({
                    '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                    '-o-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)'
            });
      }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<img src="images/hand_logo.png" handdirection>
```

Comment: Move your event code inside the directive link function and the element transform code inside the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
angular.module('cvApp')
  .directive('handdirection', function ($rootScope,getangle) {

    var current = 0;
    var angle = 0;

    return {
      template: '',
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //handle $routeChangeSuccess instead
           $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, params) {
              current = params.pos;
              var getxelement = angular.element(document).find('#secondrowelement').width();
              var getyelement = angular.element(document).find('#secondrowelement').height();
              var dimension = getangle.getdimensions(getxelement,getyelement,current);
              angle = getangle.getangle(dimension);

              //I moved the code to inside $on to make it consistent. The angle should always be calculated for a route.
              element.css({
                    '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                    '-o-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)'
              });
         });

      }
    };
});
```